# Using AJAX to load WordPress pages

Tags: ajax, wordpress, dynamic

I am trying to get it so that when a link is clicked in my WordPress template, it will load that page content with AJAX without changing the page. It needs to load dynamically into my content area depending on which link is clicked.

I have never used AJAX before so I would love it if someone could help me out or point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Wade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin works and will give clues to how it works: [WordPress › AJAX Page Loader 1.5 « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-page-loader-15/)

Comment: Have you tried putting any jQuery in the pages that are being loaded with AJAX? Those pages don't seem to be finding any jQuery I put in.

Comment: With Wordpress, you ned to load jQuery in a certain way: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script  And I'd use FireBug to see what is loading on your site: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: `Compatible up to: 2.8`

Comment: @StenW: the OP's question is more than **three** years old.

Comment: I know, thats why I added it. Unnecessary that someone else to find out on thier own that the plugin has not been worked on for some time and is not compatible with modern versions of WP.

Answer (score 11):

I was unable to get that "AJAX Page Loader 1.5" plugin to work with the latest version of Wordpress (currently 3.1.2).. so I did MUCH digging around and found this tutorial "[How To AJAXify WordPress Theme](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html)" which was super easy to follow and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jQuery, you could start by checking out their [AJAX API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). There are plenty of examples in there, too!